# excel: how to filter for a specific ID given time constraints on a text field

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel sheet that has a three fields:

`USER_ID | DATE_CREATED | TAGS`

Tags applied to the items in the sheet vary quite a bit, and are set up like |`tag1 tag2 tag3...`| within the field.

I want to get a list of all unique user IDs that acquired a certain tag at any point (`tagx`), but did not have another, different tag at any point prior to that (`tagy`).

Given the variability in times when the users could have acquired `tagx`, I'm not sure the best way to set this up.

How would I go about structuring my worksheet to filter for this information? I'm happy to set up additional helper columns that do testing, and to create pivottables.

EDIT: updated to better explain -- the fields included are just those fields that are available to me to complete this sort. The output that I'm looking for is, in any form, a list of all unique user IDs that acquired `tagx` at any point, but did not have `tagy` before they acquired `tagx`.

EDIT(1): here's a picture demonstrating what I'm looking for:

[image: example data]

in this case I would want a way to grab ID #2 (and others like it) because it acquires and retains tagx on 1/3/2001 and does not have tagy before it

but I would want to exclude ID #1 because, although it also picks up and keeps tagx on 1/2/2001, it has tagy beforehand

Comment: Can you give an example how it should look prior and after the filtering? Maybe with 2 little sceenshots

Comment: I don’t understand how the “date created” really fits into the question.  Please explain that more clearly, and/or illustrate it in your example.  It would probably help to have examples that cover all possible combinations that you want to distinguish among: e.g., a user that had `tagx` but had `tagy` earlier, a user that had `tagx` but got `tagy` later, a user that had `tagx` but never had `tagy`, a user that never had `tagx`, etc.  It would probably also help it you described your real-world problem.

Comment: now updated with better explanation

Comment: So you want to go through the `ID` column and find the first time (chronologically) that each `ID` gets `tag (any)` and then check to see if that is `tag (x)` and if not, go to the next unique `ID`? And then what? Highlight each one that fits criteria?

Comment: close, the tags field will actually have an arbitrary number of tags in it separated by a space, I want to find the first instance of tagx specifically and make sure that no prior rows have tagy in them.

Comment: so for instance `B3` could `=tagz, tagx, tagy` and you would need to locate your tag in that string that varies in length?

Comment: That's a bit much. I urge you to begin a macro and then come back when you run into an issue.